# Google BigQuery: Why a table resulted from a union of different tables is not showing any values in preview mode? Only it does when running the query?

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

I have created the following table Called GDN All accounts which resulted from the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `GDNA`
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM   `GDNB`
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM   `GDNC`
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM   `GDND
SELECT * FROM   `GDNE`
```

However, once I have opened the table in preview mode it did not show any values only it did when I have re-run the query.

Moreover, my final aim is to connect this table to PowerBi, still once in PowerBi and connected to the data source no values are showing up only nulls.

Someone can help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect and collect data separately from each table. Once this is done, first check all tables are having your expected data or not.

If you found all tables containing expected data, you can now create a new table using Append option in power query. This new table will contain all data together as per your expectation.

Remember, in preview mode not all data shown always if there are big amount of data in the source. You will get the complete list in table visual in the report.